# Hash Table Crash in C

Tags: c, hashtable, minimax

I have been trying to program my own chess engine in C language as a hobby.
i'm not familiar with programming in general.
After implementing transpositions tables i figured i could use the same concept to make my engine aware of the three fold repetition rule.
i used the same 64 bit keys i used for the transpositions tables that seem to work just fine. Never crashed at least.
I played a few moves against the program on various positions and it seemed to work well, but i eventually found out it crashes on certain positions.

this is how my code looks like:

```
#define MAX_POSITIONS 9999991

int *PositionsPlayed;
int *PositionsThinking     

int main(void){

  PositionsPlayed=malloc(MAX_POSITIONS*sizeof(int)); 
  memset(PositionsPlayed,0,MAX_POSITIONS*sizeof(int));    //this is probably useless, but whatever      

  PositionsThinking=malloc(MAX_POSITIONS*sizeof(int));
  memset(PositionsThinking,0,MAX_POSITIONS*sizeof(int));

  int depth=8,value;

  while(1){

    value=minimax( -infinite, infinite, WHITE);

    if( MakeMove()==EndOfGame ){break;}

    long long unsigned int key=GetKey(board,BlackToMove);

    PositionsPlayed[key%MAX_POSITIONS]++;  //add position to the table. Program crashes here.
    if( PositionsPlayed[key%MAX_POSITIONS]>=3 ){break;} //3fold draw

    if( MakeUserMove()==EndOfGame ){break;}

    key=GetKey(board,WhiteToMove);
    PositionsPlayed[key%MAX_POSITIONS]++;  //add position to the table
    if( PositionsPlayed[key%MAX_POSITIONS]>=3 ){break;} //3fold draw

    copy(PositionsPlayed,PositionsThinking);
  }  
}
```

minimax look like something like this:

```
int minimax( int alpha ,int beta ,int depth, bool side){

 unsigned long long int key=GetKey();

 PositionsThinking[key%MAX_POSITIONS]++;

 if(PositionsThinking[key%MAX_POSITIONS]>=3){
   PositionsThinking[key%MAX_POSITIONS]--;
   return 0;
 }

 if( !depth ){
   PositionsThinking[key%MAX_POSITIONS]--;
   return evaluate();
 }

 int bestValue;

 if (WHITE){

   bestValue := −∞
   for ( moves ){
     v := max(v,minimax(alpha, beta, depth − 1, BLACK));
     alpha := max(alpha, v);
     PositionsThinking[key%MAX_POSITIONS]--;
     return alpha;
 }
 else{  
   bestValue := +∞
   for ( moves ){
   v := min(v,minimax(alpha, beta, depth − 1, WHITE));
   beta := min(beta, v);
   PositionsThinking[key%MAX_POSITIONS]--;
   return beta;    
   }
 }
```

The PositionsThinking table goes back to the main loop with the same entries it had before calling minimax, as expected. It could go without it, it's just there because i thought it would have helped me to debug.
The program works fine most of the time and so far i have only found one certain position where it crashes and only at depth 8 and above.
GetKey() in that position is not 0;
Key is a zobris hash and has nothing to do with depth.
trying to access any variable of PositionsPlayed (eg PositionsPlayed[3]) after the minimax call will result in a crash.
Changing MAX_POSITIONS eliminates the problem but i'm guessing it will just represent itself on some other position.

Can somebody explain to me what's going on there?

Comment: what is `WHITE` : a macro ? :: `if (WHITE){` should probably be `if (side == WHITE){`

Comment: ye it should be if (side)  . I just realized i copied some pseudo code from wiki for brevitas and actually made a mess. minimax doesn't even have the same arguments it is called with in main. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: What about `bestValue := −∞`? or `v := minimax`? That's not C.

Comment: Initial guess: your `getKey()` function (not shown) returns negative values. And infinite and -infinite (both *integer* values) are suspect, too.

Comment: This isn't real code.  Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `i'm not familiar with programming in general.` 0) make the program smaller (smaller functions; thus more functions, test them) 1) make the problem smaller (smaller board, smaller transposition table) causing problems to occur *faster*

Comment: Suggest always checking the return of `[m][c][re]alloc()` functions before using the pointer they return.   If allocation fails, these functions will return NULL.

Comment: You explicitly bring the `GetKey()` function into the discussion of the problem, but do not include it in your code examples.  Also, as others have noted, the code examples you show  are not C.  Please re-edit and replace you pseudo-code with actual code :)  Consider using _[this method](http://sscce.org/)_ to convey your question.

Comment: While you're learning, I suggest you avoid doing your own dynamic allocations a la `PositionsPlayed=malloc(MAX_POSITIONS*sizeof(int));`, pointers, and instead use `std::vector<int>` and the `.at(n)` notation for indexing, which will generate an exception you can catch if you accidentally index outside the valid indices.  That will remove several classes of errors you may otherwise struggle with.